# How do you handle a statustip on the parent winform by a child winform?

Tags: winforms, parent

my code:

**in parent_Form:**

```
    public parent_Form()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        child ch = new child();
        ch.MdiParent = this;
        ch.Show();
    }
    public string label
    {
        set
        {
            textBox1.Text = value;
        }
    }
```

**in child form:**

```
    public child()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void write_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        parent_Form paren = new parent_Form();
        paren.label = "i am vietnamese";
    }
```

**but**
 "i am vietnamese" doesn't display on textbox1 (it is on parent winform)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JRoughan's solution should work. Make sure you have the button click handler properly specified. Set a breakpoint in the handler to make sure it is being executed when you click the button. I tested this and it works.

```
public child()
{
  InitializeComponent();
}

private void write_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    parent_Form paren = ((parent_Form)MdiParent);
    paren.label = "i am vietnamese";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
parent_Form paren = new parent_Form();
```

Is creating a new parent_Form which is never shown. You need to reference the actual parent like so:

```
((parent_Form)MdiParent).label = "i am vietnamese";
```